# SUM only hours in2 datetime column SQL

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin

In my database I have 2 column who has DATETIME as variable (starts & ends): [db](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eEHZB.png)
What I'm trying to do it's to SUM the hours between *starts* and *ends*.

I tried `SELECT DATEDIFF(starts, ends) AS myTotal FROM assenze`
<- (assenze is the table i'm currently working with)

But this is the [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g4l6W.png)

I know for sure it's not correct, like the first one should be 8H

Can someone help me pls?

Comment: DateDiff() is the wrong function. If you [read the docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff) it explains that function returns the number of *days* between two dates, not time. The function you want is [TimestampDiff()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff)

Comment: Oh okay, thanks. Didnt find anything about that. I'm new to this world, didnt know about Docs (it did works)